# Association and Dependency between 2 classes UML Diagram

Tags: java, dependencies, uml, associations

My question is if between 2 classes we can have both a relation of Association and Dependency in the same time. I suppose that if we have a association between 2 classes the dependency is already included. 
For example:

```
abstract class CarDealer {
  protected String name;
  protected int soldCars;
  public Car (String name) {...}
  public abstract int getSoldCars(){...}
  public void sellCar(){...}
}

public class SimpleCarDealer extends CarDealer{
  private CarDealer bestColleague;
  public SimpleCarDealer(String name){...}
  public int getSoldCars(){...}
  public void serBestColleadue(CarDealer cd){...}
}
```

Comment: You can have more than one relationship between the same pair of classes.  If you do, then they can be of different types.

Comment: _"I suppose that if we have a association between 2 classes the dependency is already included."_ yes the dependency is implicit. Anyway you can also have the dependency if necessary, this is not forbidden

Comment: It seems like in this case you have both a Generalization (`extends Cardealer` ) and an Association (`private CarDealer bestColleague;`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An association is a stronger form of a dependency. So once you have an association (that is at least one class can "see" the other through a property) you already have a dependency. A dependency is sometimes used in an early design phase and later being replaced by an association. In that case you remove the dependency. (Of course when there is an association you evidently have a dependency, don't you?) You will show just a dependency if there is no property and one class uses the other one e.g. as parameter in operations.

Answer (score 0):

When looking on the semantics of UML you cannot omit the dependency in general. Because, by definition, the "specification or implementation" of the dependent element depends on the specificatin or implemenation of the independent element. In contrast, an association is a relation between instances of these associated types. One consequence is that, when beeing associeted the specifications of both classes are still independent.